# Is there anyway to check on what is calculating this column?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Is there any tools on SQL that can track on where this column is getting it's data or on what the definition is for the column name?

I'm trying to find out why the average worked hours by weekly is off from what the total worked hours is telling me. 
[image]

Comment: check the objects that depends on this table

Comment: Is this an output of `SELECT * ` query on table/ view or result of SP?

Comment: Yes it is an output of SELECT *

Comment: In the Object Explorer, right-click on the table name, the choose Script Table As > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window.